# JavaScript Debugging on macOS

Tags: javascript, ios, software-testing, macos, safari

So I have a web app that I created in Visual Studio, and we use it on all main browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge/ IE). We also have an app on the play store/ app store but we want to get away from that and strictly use our web app for mobile.

My question is this: I want to test this web app on Safari on my mobile device (I have an iPhone X, but also have a Mac that I can use the iOS simulator on) and need to find JavaScript errors that come up. On a computer I can use the chrome dev tools, or the JavaScript console on Safari.

How can I see JavaScript errors on mobile safari? Can I plug my device in and use the Safari JavaScript console? Can I use the simulator and get the JavaScript console somehow?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out my own answer. Hopefully this helps someone down the line.

To use your own iOS device:
1. On your iOS device, go to settings -> safari -> advanced, and toggle on javascript and web developer. 
2. Plug device into Mac
3. On Safari Develop tab (turn on in settings -> advanced)select your device, then open the javascript menu. As you use your web app on your device, javascript errors will appear on the console on your Mac.

To use the simulator:
1. On the simulator, go to settings -> safari -> advanced, and toggle on javascript (it is on by default). 
2. On Safari Develop tab (turn on in settings -> advanced)select the simulator, then open the javascript menu. As you use your web app on the simulator, javascript errors will appear on the console on your Mac.